# How to modify This angularjs function to retrieve range between two dates

Tags: angularjs

How can I modify this angular function to retrieve range of dates. For now its looping 20 times. How can I only retrieve date from Date().getFullYear(); --> Which is current year till 2020. So in range it should display 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020.

```
$scope.myfunction = function () {
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    var range = [];
    range.push(year);
    for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        range.push(year + i);
    }
    return range;
}


<select ng-options="year for year in myfunction()" name="year" ng-model="year" required>
    <option value selected disabled>select year</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. You can set the end year or pass to the function as an argument.

```
$scope.myfunction = function (endYear) {
      var range = [];
      var startYear = new Date().getFullYear();
      endYear = endYear || 2020;

      while ( startYear <= endYear ) {
             range.push(startYear++);
      } 

      return range;
```

}

Comment: what if i dont pass anything here `select ng-options="year for year in myfunction()" ` I mean inside function

Comment: would it pick 2020 as default

Comment: Yes it should pickup 2020 if you don't pass anything. Also if 2020 is a fixed date and not need to change you can remove the argument on the function altogether.